# remove array from multidimensional array if first 3 values aren't unique in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

OK, so I have this array of arrays.  Each array within the larger array is very much the same, ten specific values.  If my value at location 3 is a specific value, then I want to iterate through the rest of the remaining arrays within the larger array and see if the first 3 values at locations 0, 1, and 2 match.  if they then match, I'd like to delete the original array.  I'm having a hard time with it, maybe there is an easy way?  I'm sure there is, I'm fairly new to this whole coding stuff =) So much appreciation in advance for your help....

here's where I'm at:

```
@projectsandtrials.each do |removed|
  if removed[3] == ["Not Harvested"]
    @arraysforloop = @projectsandtrials.clone
    @arraysforloop1 = @arraysforloop.clone.delete(removed)
    @arraysforloop1.each do |m|
      if (m & [removed[0], removed[1], removed[2]]).any?
        @projectsandtrials.delete(removed)
      end
    end


  end

end
```

Comment: The problem I'm having is that my first array is deleted from @projectsandtrials and it shouldn't be...but everything else is fine...

Comment: Please edit to give a small example, including your intended result. Rather than the arrays being of size 10, make them smaller--say 5 elements. If you wish, feel free to use the example I gave in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets look at your situation:

```
@projectsandtrials.each do |removed|
  // some logic, yada yada
  @projectsandtrials.delete(removed) 
end
```

You can't just delete stuff out of an array you're iterating through. At least not until you finish iterating through it. What you should be using instead is a filtering method like [`reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject-21) instead of just an [`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each).

So instead of deleting right there, you should just return true when using reject.

I think about it like this when iterating through arrays.

Do I want the array to stay the same size and have the same content?
Use [each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each).

Do I want the array to be the same size, but have different content?
Use [map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map).

Do I want the array to be less than or equal to the current size?
Use [select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) or [reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject).

Do I want it to end up being a single value?
Use [reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce).

Comment: Thanks @arjabbar, and everyone else for that matter.  My initial solution was pretty simple - like you say, I needed to wait to delete my array until I finished the iteration.  So that worked, but I also went ahead and cleaned it up and refactored it to use the reject method!  Thanks to all! Always a learning experience and good to hear the different ways of thinking!

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
def prune(arr, val)
  arr.values_at(*(0..arr.size-4).reject { |i| arr[i][3] == val &&
    arr[i+1..i+3].transpose[0,3].map(&:uniq).all? { |a| a.size==1 } }.
      concat((arr.size-3..arr.size-1).to_a))
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = [ [1,2,3,4,0],
        [3,4,5,6,1],
        [3,4,5,4,2],
        [3,4,5,6,3],
        [3,4,5,6,4],
        [3,4,0,6,5],
        [2,3,5,4,6],
        [2,3,5,5,7],
        [2,3,5,7,8],
        [2,3,5,8,9],
        [2,3,5,7,0]
      ]
```

Notice that the last values of the elements (arrays) of `arr` are consecutive. This is to help you identify the elements of `prune(arr, 4)` (below) that have been dropped.

```
prune(arr, 4)   
   # => [[3, 4, 5, 6, 1],
   #     [3, 4, 5, 4, 2],
   #     [3, 4, 5, 6, 3],
   #     [3, 4, 5, 6, 4],
   #     [3, 4, 0, 6, 5],
   #     [2, 3, 5, 5, 7],
   #     [2, 3, 5, 7, 8],
   #     [2, 3, 5, 8, 9],
   #     [2, 3, 5, 7, 0]]
```

**Explanation**

The arrays at indices `0` and `6` have not been included in array returned.

`arr[0]` (`[1,2,3,4,0]`) has not been included because `arr[0][3] = val = 4` and `arr[1]`, `arr[2]` and `arr[3]` all begin `[3,4,5]`.

`arr[6]` (`[2,3,5,4,6]`) has not been included because `arr[6][3] = 4` and `arr[7]`, `arr[8]` and `arr[9]` all begin `[2,3,5]`.

`arr[2]` (`[3,4,5,5,2]`) has been included because, while `arr[2][3] = 4`, `arr[3][0,3]`, `arr[4][0,3]` and `arr[5][0,3]` all not all equal (i.e., `arr[5][2] = 0`).

Notice that the last three elements of `arr` will always be included in the array returned.

Now let's examine the calculations. First consider the following.

```
arr.size
  #=> 11

a = (0..arr.size-4).reject { |i| arr[i][3] == val &&
  arr[i+1..i+3].transpose[0,3].map(&:uniq).all? { |a| a.size==1 } }
  #=> (0..7).reject { |i| arr[i][3] == val &&
    arr[i+1..i+3].transpose[0,3].map(&:uniq).all? { |a| a.size==1 } }
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

Consider `reject`'s block calculation for `i=0` (recall `val=4`).

```
arr[i][3] == val && arr[i+1..i+3].transpose[0,3].map(&:uniq).all? {|a| a.size==1 }}
  #=> 4 == 4 && arr[1..3].transpose[0,3].map(&:uniq).all? { |a| a.size==1 }
  #=> [[3,4,5,6,1],
  #    [3,4,5,4,2],
  #    [3,4,5,6,3]].transpose[0,3].map(&:uniq).all? { |a| a.size==1 }
  #=> [[3, 3, 3],
  #    [4, 4, 4],
  #    [5, 5, 5],
  #    [6, 4, 6],
  #   [1, 2, 3]][0,3].map(&:uniq).all? { |a| a.size==1 }
  #=> [[3, 3, 3],
  #    [4, 4, 4],
  #    [5, 5, 5]].map(&:uniq).all? { |a| a.size==1 }
  #=> [[3], [4], [5]].all? { |a| a.size==1 }
  #=> true
```

meaning `arr[0]` is to be rejected; i.e., not included in the returned array.
The remaining block calculations (for `i=1,...,10`) are similar.

We have computed

```
a #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

which are the indices of all elements of `arr` except the last `3` that are to be retained. To `a` we add the indices of the last three elements of `arr`.

```
b = a.concat((arr.size-3..arr.size-1).to_a)
  #=> a.concat((8..10).to_a)
  #=> a.concat([8,9,10])
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Lastly,

```
arr.values_at(*b)
```

returns the array given in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet seems fine, although there are couple of things to note:

1. `@arraysforloop.clone.delete(removed)` removes all the occurences of `removed` array (not only the first one). E.g. [1,2,3,1].delete(1) would leave you with [2,3]. You could fix it with using an iterator for `@projectsandtrials` and [delete_at](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/delete_at) method.
2. `delete` method returns the same argument you pass to it (or nil if no matches found). So `@arraysforloop1 = @arraysforloop.clone.delete(removed)` makes your `@arraysforloop1` to contain the removed array's elements only! Removing an assignment could save you.
3. I see no reason to have two cloned arrays, `@arraysforloop` and `@arraysforloop1`, as the former one is not used anyhow later. May be we could omit one of them?
4. `@projectsandtrials.delete(removed)` leaves you in a strange state, as long as you're iterating the same array right now. This could end up with you missing the right next element after the removed one. Here is a simple snippet to illustrate the behaviour:

   ```
   > a = [1,2,3]
   > a.each{|e, index| puts("element is: #{e}"); a.delete(1);}
   element is: 1
   element is: 3
   ```

   As you see, after deleting element `1` the loop moved to element `3` directly, omitting the `2` (as it became the first element in array and algorithm thinks it's been handled already).

One of the possibilities to make it less messy is to split it to a bundle of methods. Here is an option:

```
def has_searched_element? row
  # I leave this method implementation to you
end

def next_rows_contain_three_duplicates?(elements, index)
  # I leave this method implementation to you
end

def find_row_ids_to_remove elements
  [].tap do |result|
    elements.each_with_index do |row, index|
      condition = has_searched_element?(row) && next_rows_contain_three_duplicates?(elements, index)
      result << index if condition
    end
  end
end

row_ids_to_remove = find_row_ids_to_remove(@projectsandtrials)
# now remove all the elements at those ids out of @projectsandtrials
```